# mySQL - Do the operations and store in table or do the math every time I fetch the data

Tags: mysql

As simple as that, what's better in terms of performance? I'm doing some calculations based on user data input (simple arithmetic), should I do the operations and store the result in the database or do the operation each time I do the SELECT query?

Option 1: operate each time I fetch data from the table

```
SELECT 
  some_random_fields,
  salary,
  extra_days,
  extra_days * salary * 0.05 AS extra_income 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  user_id = 'xxx'
```

Option 2: operate once, INSERT INTO table, fetch result without operating (extra column)

```
SELECT 
  some_random_fields,
  salary,
  extra_days,
  extra_income 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  user_id = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Do you ever expect even the slightest outside possibility of the calculation changing? (for instance a different multiplier than 0.05)

Comment: In theory doing the math every time is more time-consuming. But the difference will probably be irrelevant unless you have a huge amount of data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I store a calculate value in my database along with the variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529586/should-i-store-a-calculate-value-in-my-database-along-with-the-variables)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski there are like 4 scenarios, each one have an specific multiplier, but I can check which situation it is with PHP and then execute the appropriate query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it depends.

In the case you've described, it would clearly be advantageous to do the calculations at the time they're needed, because the salary or percentage (`0.05`)  can clearly change over time (people get raises or demotions, reduction in hours, etc., or the current economy calls for using `0.04` instead of `0.05`), and it's better to calculate it as needed than to have to update the entire database to store new `extra_income`. The cost of the calculation (especially when limited in scope to a single `user` by the `WHERE`) is negligible compared to the accuracy of the calculation and the elimination of the need to remember to update all of the data when things change.

If the data is static (rarely or never changes), or you need to retain the values (for some historical reason, or for an audit trail), do the calculation up front and store it. The extra space used isn't typically an issue, and since the data is static there's no need to repeat the calculations every time you're doing a `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact what I put was an example, what I'm doing are calculating some benefits that every employer have to pay to the employees according to my country's legislation, there are a few variations that depends of the time the worker have in the company, but nothing too complicated.

I guess I'll do the calculation each time, as I'll give the opportunity to the users to modify the data in case of a mistake, so each time they update the information I don't have to modify an extra field in the table

Comment: If they're not complicated, do them as needed to minimize the need to do mass updates when things change. (And government-required benefits frequently change, at least where I live (the US). Tax information, for instance, changes every single year, as does the cost of health insurance.)

Comment: In my particular case it's a single law that was modified last year, and the previous one was from 1996. Although I see your point... I need to put the pros and cons in a balance. The reason I want to do the operations each time the data is fetched is mainly to simplify the process when the user updates the information.

Comment: Well, I come to give an update in case someone is in a similar situation. I ended up doing the calculations as needed, its easier to mantain, you just change the query that returns the calculated data, and it's pretty fast. As I'm kind of a mySQL noob I needed to investigate a lot about variables and conditionals in mySQL, but it's worth it. I loaded 70.000 records to try how it will behave with a populated database, and it's still lightning fast, the concerns about query speed are important with really big databases, not my case though. EXPLAIN is your friend