# Sql server Balance Table Update Recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I Have a SQL Server database with a table named Balance

The table:

| Id | Date | IN | OUT | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3345312 | 2022-08-07 | 100 | 50 | 250 |
| 5435245 | 2022-08-06 | 50 | 50 | 200 |
| 4353451 | 2022-08-05 | 0 | 100 | 200 |
| 5762454 | 2022-08-04 | 20 | 100 | 300 |
| 7634523 | 2022-08-03 | 400 | 100 | 380 |
| 5623456 | 2022-08-02 | 100 | 20 | 80 |
| 4524354 | 2022-08-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

- Id = Unique Identifier
- Date = Balance Date
- IN = IN Ammount
- OUT = OUT Ammount
- Balance = Last Day Balance + IN - OUT

The value of **Balance** column always should be equal to
(Last Day Balance + IN - OUT)

That is, if on 2022-08-04 the number of entries is changed from 20 to 100, the balance from 2022-08-04 onwards must be recalculated:

| Id | Date | IN | OUT | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3345312 | 2022-08-07 | 100 | 50 | 330 |
| 5435245 | 2022-08-06 | 50 | 50 | 280 |
| 4353451 | 2022-08-05 | 0 | 100 | 280 |
| 5762454 | 2022-08-04 | 100 | 100 | 380 |

I've tried to make a recursive query to update this balance

It didn't worked. It just updates the balance of the day I updated ignoring the next days.

Here is what I did until now:

```
        DECLARE @BalanceDate DATE = '2022-09-04';

        DECLARE @BalanceLastDay DECIMAL(19,5) = (SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(Balance, 0) 
                        Balances
                        WHERE BalanceDate < @BalanceDate 
                        ORDER BY BalanceDate DESC);

        WITH Inventory AS 
        (
            SELECT Id, BalanceDate, IN, OUT, Balance, 
                    LAG(Balance) OVER (ORDER BY BalanceDate) AS BalanceLastDay,
            FROM Balances
            WHERE BalanceDate >=  @BalanceDate)
        ),
        InventoryUpdated AS
        (
            SELECT inv.*, 
            (COALESCE(BalanceLastDay, @BalanceLastDay) + IN - OUT) AS RealBalance,
            FROM Inventory inv
        )
        UPDATE Balances SET Saldo = invUpdt.SaldoReal
            FROM Balances INNER JOIN InventoryUpdated invUpdt on Balances.Id = invUpdt.Id
            WHERE invUpdt.Saldo <> invUpdt.SaldoReal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
Select Id, [Date], [IN], [OUT],
       SUM([IN] - [OUT]) Over (Order By [Date]) AS Balance
From your_table
Order By [Date] DESC;
```

`SUM([IN] - [OUT]) Over (Order By [Date])` will calculate the cumulative sum of (IN - OUT) over the increasing of date.

***Note***: I think it's not a good practice to store the balance value in the table because it's a calculated value, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529586/should-i-store-a-calculate-value-in-my-database-along-with-the-variables).

But if you want to do that you may use updatable CTE as the following:

```
With CTE AS 
(
    Select Id, Balance,
           SUM([IN] - [OUT]) Over (Order By [Date]) AS bl
    From your_table
) 
Update CTE Set Balance = bl;
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5zWuho1).

***Update***, according to the new requirement stated in the comments, that you have multiple products in the table and you want to perform the update on a specific product from a specific date up.

To find the running/ cumulative sum for multiple products you have to add `Partition By Pid` to the `Over` clause, where Pid is the product Id, so the select query will be:

```
Select Pid, Id, [Date], [IN], [OUT],
       SUM([IN] - [OUT]) Over (Partition By Pid Order By [Date]) AS Balance
From your_table
Order By Pid, [Date] DESC;
```

And the update query:

```
Update your_table Set [in] = 100 Where [Date] = '2022-08-04' And Pid = 1;

With CTE AS 
(
    Select Pid, Id, Balance, Date, [IN] ,[OUT],
           SUM([IN] - [OUT]) Over (Partition By Pid Order By [Date]) AS bl
    From your_table
) 
Update CTE Set Balance = bl Where [Date] >= '2022-08-04' And Pid = 1;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E86vhniY).

Comment: The balance is not IN - OUT
Its (Balance of Yesterday + IN - OUT)
You missed the balance of Yesterday in your query

Comment: The balance of yesterday (previous day) is already included, this is a cumulative sum, which means the sum of all previous up to current.

Comment: Have you checked the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5zWuho1)? The query outputs exactly what you want!

Comment: Sorry. I saw now. It worked perfectly. You are my hero now. Thanks!! But there is one thing that didn't worked as well. This way, I have to update the entire table every time I update the IN-OUT. I want to update only from the updated date onwards. This is updated a lot of times for a lot of different products. I can't update the entire table everytime.

Comment: You’re most welcome. So you want to perform this on multiple products, and update only from the date of change for a specific product only, that implies that there's a product id column in the table, right?

Comment: Yes !! My question has a very short version of my table. Only to simplify. But you're right. My balance table is segregated by Product, Deposit and batch.

Comment: Check the updated answer.